# Why doesn't the compiler complain about adding char to char*?

Tags: c++, char-pointer

Why c++ compiler doesn't complain for the following code?

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    const char* p ="Hello";
    std::string q = p + 'H';
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
}
```

And it rightly thrown error for the the following code

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    const char* p ="Hello";
    std::string q = p + "World";
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
}
```

Error statements thrown by compiler

```
test.cxx: In function 'int main()':
test.cxx:5: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [6]' to binary 'operator+'
```

Can someone help me in understanding, why first code didn't thrown any error statement?

Comment: May be due to **'H'** at  `std::string q = p + 'H';`, try it with **"H"**

Answer (score 6):

`'H'` is a character, an integral type. So `p + 'H'` is the same as `&p['H']` (you are indexing based on the numeric value of `'H'`). The first snippet has undefined behavior since the numeric value of `'H'` is probably much greater than 6, but the compiler is free not to complain about undefined behavior.

On the other hand `"World"` is not an integral type, nor is it convertible to one. So the addition cannot be performed, point blank.

Answer (score 2):

`'H'` is a *single* character, its type is `char`. A `char` can be implicitly converted to `int`, so it will add this value to the pointer `p` (Advance it by that value).

Note that it is still undefined behavior because the new pointer `q` points outside of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Both don't perform string concatenatation (as you might expect).

For `p + 'H'`, pointer arithmetic is performed. `'H'` is treated as an integer with value `72`, then `p + 'H'` will try to return the pointer pointing to the 73th element of the array `"Hello"`, it's getting out of the bound and leads to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means anything is possible; the compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic for it.

For `p + "World"`, you're adding two pointers (i.e. `const char*`), which doesn't make sense at all.

I suppose you want to do string concatenatation, then you should use `std::string` instead of pointer like `std::string p ="Hello";`, or use [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (from C++14), e.g. `std::string q = p + "World"s;`, both would perform string concatenatation for you.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
std::string q = p + "World";
```

the string literal `"World"` is converted to pointer to its first character and has the type `const char *`.

So there is an attempt to add two pointers. Such an operation does not defined and the compiler issued an error.

In this statement

```
std::string q = p + 'H';
```

there is used a valid operation of adding an integer value `'H'` (that is implicitly converted to the type `int` due to the integral promotion to a pointer. That is in the expression used as an initializer there is used the so-called pointer arithmetic. The compiler does not check whether the result pointer points to beyond the string literal. So neither diagnostic is issued.

Answer (score 0):

Because adding a char litteral 'H' is like adding any other valid char value  to the char, whereas adding "Hello" means adding a pointer to a string which is obviously an incompatible type.